# Как сделать мультиплатформенную игру с сохранениями?

Tags: разработка-игр

может быть кто-нибудь знает как это можно решить. У меня появилась идея создать игру с  сохранениями прогресса так, чтобы, например, на компьютере я прошёл до определённой локации в игре, прогресс сохранился и как сделать так, чтобы я смог позже продолжить с того же места играть на телефоне? (Мультиплатформенная игра) Какими путями это можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Дык решение только одно - загружать сохранения в сеть.

Comment: Ну если простенькая аркада, то можно как в начале 90х было - раз в несколько уровней показывать игроку код, при вводе которого на старте игры игрок начинает не с первого уровня, а с того, перед которым показали код. Так было например в серии prehistoric.